# How to deal with duplicated Service started with START_STICKY?

Tags: java, android, service

I have a service that is starting in MainActivity when app is launched.

I want it to run even after my app is killed so I have following onStartCommand.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

The problem is when I start the app, kill it, wait until service is automatically restarted, then I restart the app. After that another service instance is created and I have 2 running services (one bound to MainActivity and one created by START_STICKY).

MainActivity:

```
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
    
    startService(serviceIntent);
    serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            ServiceBinder binder = (ServiceBinder) iBinder;
            service = binder.getService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        }
    };
    bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Logs:

I start the app

```
D/Service: onCreate: called 47793fd
D/Service: onStartCommand: called 47793fd
D/Service: onBind: called 47793fd
D/Service: service running 47793fd
```

I kill the process (Why is onDestroy called after onCreate here?)

```
D/Service: onUnbind: called 47793fd
D/Service: onCreate: called 9d89377
D/Service: onDestroy: called 9d89377
D/Service: service running 9d89377
```

I restart the app

```
D/Service: onCreate: called 32b044a
D/Service: onStartCommand: called 32b044a
D/Service: onBind: called 32b044a
D/Service: service running 32b044a
D/Service: service running 9d89377
```

Body of method running inside the service:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = 
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(CORE_POOL_SIZE);

    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> 
    //do something
        Log.d(TAG, "service running " + this.toString().split("@")[1]);
    }), 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Can I bind that service running in the background to MainActivity or kill it when app restarts?

Comment: "After that another service instance is created and I have 2 running services (one bound to MainActivity and one created by START_STICKY)" -- since that is not how services have ever behaved, what is your evidence for this?

Comment: @CommonsWare check those logs I've just put into the post, please.

Comment: That just shows that you are leaking a thread, by failing to clean up your `ScheduledExecutorService` when the first service instance is destroyed. It also suggests that your process is not being terminated.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not sure if that's the case since the original service 47793fd is not working anymore, the working services are 9d89377 (the copy created by START_STICKY) and 32b044a (created after second restart). But I guess I can try and check it out, should I put scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdown() inside onDestroy of service to properly clean it up?

Comment: btw: do you have any idea why is onDestroy called after onCreate of that START_STICKY service copy?

Comment: "should I put scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdown() inside onDestroy of service to properly clean it up?" -- yes. If you start a thread in a service, it is your responsibility to stop the thread. "do you have any idea why is onDestroy called after onCreate of that START_STICKY service copy?" -- no, though I have a vague memory of seeing that sort of behavior years ago.